# указание типажа как типа переменой в структуре

Tags: rust

как можно использовать типаж в качестве типа переменой. пробовал так:

```
pub trait Controller {
    fn update();
}

pub struct GameObject{
    controller: Controller
}
```

но выдаёт ошибку компиляции

> [E0038] the trait `Controller` cannot be made into an object

как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так ?

```
struct GameObject{
    controller: Box<Controller>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что у типажа неизвестен размер, поэтому у такой структуры тоже не будет известен размер и компилятор не знает, как ее располагать в памяти. Можно как выше написали, а еще можно так:

```
struct GameObject<T: Controller>{
    controller: T
}
```

Тогда конкретный тип будет везде известен. Но тогда везде придется писать этот генрик.

Comment: Стоит отметить разницу между статическим и динамическим использованием. В примере с `Box`, методы на `controller` будут вызываться динамически через vtable. `Box<Controller>` инициализируется с выделением памяти в глобальной куче. В вашем примере, вызовы компилируются статически и объект размещается непосредственно в поле структуры.